# PDFmake "unknown image format" error

Tags: javascript, html, image, bmp, pdfmake

I'm trying to put a BMP image (encoded as a base64 string) into a PDF, however it is failing with the error `Uncaught Error: Unknown image format`. I know the image is formatted correctly because it loads in pure HTML correctly like so:

```
<img src="data:image/bmp;base64,THEIMAGEINBASE64">
```

[JSFiddle of the HTML-only image here](https://jsfiddle.net/5j7s3Lc4/)

But when loading into pdfmake like so:

```
var docDefinition = {
    content: [{
        image: 'data:image/bmp;base64,THEIMAGEINBASE64'
    }]
};
pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).download('my.pdf');
```

...it fails ([JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/gwLeLutk/)).

Comment: According to [the documentation](http://pdfmake.org/#/gettingstarted), only "JPEG and PNG formats are supported."

Comment: Good find, thanks. The doco says:
**Images**
_This is simple. Just use the { image: '...' } node type.
JPEG and PNG formats are supported._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PDFMake [only accepts JPEG and PNG](http://pdfmake.org/#/gettingstarted)